# How to use geoip data for IPv6?

Tags: php, ipv6, geoip

This is the code I used

```
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$buffer= geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip); 
geoip_close($gi);
return $buffer;
```

for IPv4.

How should I modify the code to support BOTH IPv6 and IP4?

Comment: Have you tried without modifying it?

Comment: no way it'll work because the file name for .dat for the ip6 is different.

Comment: IP2Location is another option if you are looking for IPv6.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get this working, you will need to download the IPv6 database from MaxMind. You can find this at:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

After pointing geoip_open to the IPv6 file, you should be able to look up IPv6 addresses.

For example:

```
$database = (strpos($ip, ":") === false) ? "GeoIP.dat" : "GeoLiteCityv6.dat";
$gi = geoip_open($database, GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

The rest would be the same as before.

That said, you might want to consider refactoring so that you aren't opening and closing the database with each call.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's how. But is there anything from maxmind that confirm that it's indeed the way? Where do you find it? I think I copied the whole code from somewhere. I forget where.

Comment: The database is linked from the MaxMind developer site.

Comment: refactoring like how please ?